# mysql.sock is not created OSX

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard, mysql.sock

I run mysql on OSX, now when I restart my computer it does not create the mysql.sock, meaning that all my connections gives me a error 2002.

anyone knows how to prevent this?

Comment: Did MySQL actually start? If it's starting, it would create the socket automatically.

Comment: what does your mysql error log say?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, a solution that's worked for others (myself included) is posted, would be much obliged if you could mark the correct solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had this same issue on Snow Leopard, the socket spawns in the wrong location for some reason on OS X.

To get the socket spawning in the correct location:
create a new file "my.cnf" in /etc with the following lines:

```
[mysqld]
socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock

[client]
socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and restart mysqld: sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe

This will force the MySQL socket file to spawn in the proper location, and everything should work normally.  Good luck!

Comment: This question is duplicated dozens of times yet yours is the first answer that actually helped me.  It deserves more upvotes.

Comment: where is the /etc file? I'm sorry if it's s dumb question but idk what that is!

Comment: etc is a directory, not a file.  It's located under the root ("/") directory (hence "/etc").

Comment: One additional problem I ran into was that the user that mysql runs as did not have permission to edit /var/mysql/mysql.sock (I think because I created it using sudo), so I had to chmod it before things would work. Actually, MySQL wouldn't even start up until I chmodded it.

Comment: mysqld_safe command worked right away... you made my day. thank you

Answer (score 5):

I  use Mac OS 10.12  Sierra, I meet the same mysql question. I can find mysql.sock in my file system.

Resolve question method:

## 1 remove my.cnf

### sudo rm -rf /etc/my.cnf

## restart your mysql servers

### brew services restart mysql

or

### sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist

### sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist

## you can check it

sudo lost -i tcp:3306

[image]

mysql is running ok.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem on a Linux box once, and I found that the directory (/var/run/mysqld) was not writable by the user mysql runs as.  I would check that if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to execute

```
sudo find / -name "mysql.sock"
```

to be sure the file is not anywhere.

In my cas I used the command mysql with variant socket in this way

```
mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having trouble in restarting MySQL on a box running Sierra. Every time that I tried to connect after restarting my machine, I would lose the ability to connect to my MySQL instance. Based on this post, I determined that there was, indeed, no my.cnf file in my environment. I followed DashRantic's instructions to force a build of a socket file. It appears to have resolved the problem.