# MySQL data directory location

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

I installed MySQL on a Mac after downloading its DMG file version 64 bit.

While trying to create a database it gave me error 1006 -- can't create database. After browsing a number of website, it seems due to user ownership setting of MySQL "data directory" location that needs to be changed.

Where is MySQL default `data` directory? I could not find `/var/lib/mysql` in localhost.

THANKS.

Comment: You can see this link: GeekHades answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847069/mysql-sock-is-not-created-osx/41605617#41605617

Answer (score 61, accepted):

See if you have a file located under `/etc/my.cnf`.  If so, it should tell you where the data directory is.

**For example:**

```
[mysqld]
set-variable=local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
...
```

My guess is that your mysql might be installed to /usr/local/mysql-XXX.

**You may find these MySQL reference manual links useful:**

- [Installing MySQL 8.0 on MacOS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/osx-installation-pkg.html)
- [Installing MySQL 5.7 on MacOS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/osx-installation-pkg.html)
- [Installing MySQL 5.6 on MacOS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/osx-installation-pkg.html)
- [Installing MySQL 5.5 on MacOS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/osx-installation-pkg.html)

Comment: thanks a LOT paulsm4, your guess (/usr/local/mysql-xxx) is correct.. Have a good day

Comment: /usr/local/var/mysql for me!

Comment: `/usr/local/var/mysql` is the case if you've installed `mysql` with `Homebrew`

Comment: @MRT cheers! Every few weeks/months I need this information :P

Comment: XAMPP and other tools have their own data locations /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql . See http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/where_are_mysqls_files

Comment: i got it on mac from /usr/local/mysql/bin .. THEN ./mysql -u root -p

Comment: Mine (/etc/my.cnf) is just empty:
------------------
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
----------------------

I've installed mysql@5.7 from homebrew and it has not created any /usr/local/var/mysql folder.

...
this is the default installation directory: usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7

Answer (score 75):

If the software is Sequel pro the default install mysql on Mac OSX has data located here:

```
/usr/local/var/mysql
```

Comment: I installed mysql through ```HOMEBREW``` and have been having weird problems with it and for some reason it's located here?!

Comment: I'd like to confirm: if you've installed mysql through `HOMEBREW` it's located here.

Comment: I installed mysql through HOMEBREW as well and its located here:
/usr/local/mysql

Answer (score 20):

On M1 and homebrew the "data directory" is:

```
/opt/homebrew/var/mysql
```

And the main path is:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql
```

Answer (score 16):

*As suggested, I edited this message to place a proper answer.*

---

The 'physical' location of the MySQL database is under `/usr/local/mysql`

The `mysql` is a *symlink* to the current active MySQL installation, in my case the exact folder is `mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86_64`.

Inside that folder you'll see another `data` folder, inside it are RESTRICTED folders with your databases.

You can't actually see the size of your databases (that was my issue) from the Finder because the folder are protected, you can though see from the terminal with `sudo du -sh /usr/local/mysql/data/{your-database-name}` and like this you'll get a nice formatted output with the size.

In those folder you have different files with all the folders present in your database, so it's safer to check the db's folder to get a size.

That's it. Enjoy!

Comment: I take it all back, the databases are there, but the get info on the parent directory returned erroneous results. Get Info on the specific db folders will return all that occupied space.

Answer (score 14):

Well, if yo don't know where is my.cnf (such Mac OS X installed with homebrew), or You are looking found others choices:

```
ps aux|grep mysql
abkrim            1160   0.0  0.2  2913068  26224   ??  R    Tue04PM   0:14.63 /usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/opt/mariadb --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/opt/mariadb/lib/plugin --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --log-error=/usr/local/var/mysql/iMac-2.local.err --pid-file=iMac-2.local.pid
```

You get `datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql`

Answer (score 8):

Check where is the root folder of mysql with:

```
mysql_config
```

Comment: Command not found. Is `mysql_config` not included with the MySQL binaries?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **macOS *{mine 'High Sierra'}*** and Installed XAMPP

You can find mysql data files;

Go to : `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/`

Answer (score 2):

If you install MySQL via homebrew on MacOS, you might need to delete your old data directory `/usr/local/var/mysql`. Otherwise, it will fail during the initialization process with the following error:

```
==> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/bin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=hohoho --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
2019-07-17T16:30:51.828887Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) initializing of server in progress as process 93487
2019-07-17T16:30:51.830375Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2019-07-17T16:30:51.830381Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] Newly created data directory /usr/local/var/mysql/ is unusable. You can safely remove it.
2019-07-17T16:30:51.830410Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-07-17T16:30:51.830540Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  Homebrew.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Homebrew to install MySQL@5.7, the location is

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/var/mysql
```

I don't know if the location is the same for other versions.

Answer (score 0):

if its homebrew install with m1 chip then its located under

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql
```