# How do I restore MySQL .frm .MYD .MYI files in OS X Lion

Tags: mysql, database, macos, restore, osx-lion

I received a bunch of these types of files and haven't a clue as how to restore the database on my Mac. I've found instructions on how to do this on Windows, that you simply need to put these into a specific directory and the database should be restored, but I don't know which directory, or even where it would be located in OS X.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See this question, it should solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459103/mysql-data-directory-location

Comment: This question *really* should go on serverfault.

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud, I have posted it there. Hopefully I'm able to get some help and resolve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

To find you MySQL data directory, open the file `/etc/my.cnf`. It should be there if you've MySQL installed.

Find the variable datadir: `datadir=/var/lib/mysql`, create a directory under that and copy all your DB files in there, as in `/var/lib/mysql/database`, where `database` is your DB name.

In a previous version of this answer I suggested to use `sudo locate user.frm`, but it didn't work, even after running `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`. If anyone knows why, I'd like to hear.

Comment: I ran the command in Terminal, and I got this message: WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

I ran that command as well, it prompted me for my password, then ran the locate command again, and I received the same message. Help!

Comment: I'm more a Linux user, but I have a OSX Leopard virtual machine... in fact it doesn't work, even prepending `sudo`. I don't know why, it should. I am going to delete this answer, because obviously is not correct, I'm also curious to know the solution, will stay tuned.

Comment: I found the my.cnf file, but it is empty. I also noticed that I had 2 mysql folders in usr/local/. I've uploaded a screen shot of the directory, as well as the opened cnf file at http://oliverkiss.com/images/temp/mysql_1.png

Comment: Let me add a huge thank you stivlo for taking the time to help me out on this one!

Comment: I opened up Sequel Pro (a MySQL client in case you're not familiar with the application) and it successfully connects to the local MySQL database. Screen shot at http://oliverkiss.com/images/temp/mysql_2.png