# Restore Databases from Phpymyadmin

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I test Drupal websites on my site locally on Mac using Phpmyadmin.

I recently had to to do a clean reinstall of my Mac. I have a full back up of my hardrive, but I'm not sure where to locate the databases in the back up and how to restore them.

Where does Phpmyadmin store the databases?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459103/mysql-data-directory-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/usr/local/mysql/data

try it here

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin does not write any database files. It is a php client application which accesses a MySQL server.

On OSX the MySQL server creates its data files in /usr/local/mysql/data as far as I know.

**1. Stop your MySQL server**

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/mysql.server stop
```

**2. Remove new data files**

sudo mv /usr/local/mysql/data /usr/local/mysql/data.new

**3. Copy old data files from your backup and fix prrmissions**

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:wheel /usr/local/mysql/data
```

**4. Start your server again**

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/mysql.server start
```

**5. Check and optimize databases**

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqlcheck --all-databases
```

Now phpMyAdmin will show all old databases