# Where do I store database DDL scripts to use in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, macos, directory, ddl

I am trying to use DDL scripts in mySQL but I get the following error, which is related to not being able to find the file path.

mysql> source filename

"Failed to open file 'filename', error: 2"

I am working in OS X. Is there a mySQL directory somewhere? Please help!

Additionally, any resources to understand OS X file paths/hierarchy would be much appreciated!

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/7459142/1816093

Comment: try `show variables where variable_name like'data%';`

Comment: The only problem, @Drew, is that ddl scripts should not be stored in the datadir.  That's mysql's turf, not user turf.  No user-serviceable parts.

Comment: honestly, @Michael-sqlbot, I was zoomed in on this part of it `Is there a mySQL directory somewhere?` As far as I know, she is on an Airbook, and her mysql is Amazon Linux AMI

Comment: that said, that so called mysql turf is the output directory of outfile commands, which seems a little user-turf to me. Now going below that, into schema folders, and intermingling .sql with .frm and .ibd, that is mysql turf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store then wherever makes sense.  The catch is that when you `source` them, you need to either already be in that directory before running the initial `mysql` command, because `source` only looks in the current directory -- that's why they aren't found, not because you put them in the "wrong" place, if that's what you're thinking may be the problem.

Or, use the full path, e.g.:

```
mysql> source /home/melissa/myscript.sql
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand source, so thanks for telling me that the file needed to be in the current directory.