# MySQL database file on Mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

A really dumb question. I have used MySQL workbench created a new database/schema (on the same local Mac OS box), and wondering what are path of the database physical folder, which it stores data/index files?

BTW, I did search by database name, but cannot find anything. :(

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: issue a `show variables where variable_name='datadir';`  then follow up with scrutiny of folder underneath it

Comment: @Drew, thanks for answering my question. Could you add as an answer so that I can mark it as Answer to benefit other people in the future? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, either issue a `show variables where variable_name='datadir';` then follow up with scrutiny of folders underneath it. Folders are the schema/db folders.

Or look at the answer [Here on the Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459103/mysql-data-directory-location) pointing one to examining the `/etc/my.cnf` file that may contain:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

on my Windows box they would appear as

C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data>dir /ad

```
 Directory of C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data

09/13/2015  01:36 PM    <DIR>          ajax_stuff
07/14/2015  09:52 PM    <DIR>          mysql
...
11/11/2015  10:37 PM    <DIR>          so_gibberish
09/21/2015  01:10 PM    <DIR>          real_secret_stuff
```

Sorry, not on my mac at the moment

Comment: Thanks @Drew for all the help. Have a good day. :)