# Can't drop database from phpMyAdmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I needed to reinstall drupal and simply deleted the entire folder from the xampp folder (and planned to then reinstall from scratch – I assume the wrong way to do it). I now can't get rid of the database from phpMyAdmin, error showing:

**#1010 – Error dropping database (can't rmdir './drupal_db', errno: 66 "Directory not empty")**

I assume that's because I just deleted it. Any way to get rid of it? I'm super new to this so as simply as possible will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rmdir` (linux command) if the folder is empty, otherwise, you need to use `rm -r`

You can also use `bash shell` to work with DB:

```
mysql -u root -p
CREATE DATABASE drupal_db
```

or:
`DROP DATABASE drupal_db`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now I'm going to look really stupid, but where do I use these? I tried the Terminal (I'm on a Mac) and it didn't work.

Comment: You probably need to [get root](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012) privileges:

[sudo su](http://serverfault.com/questions/43362/su-not-working-on-mac-os-x)

Then, you need to find "drupal_db" and remove it manually.
in the Linux terminal, it would be: `find / -name "drupal_db"`

Check [where is the root folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459103/mysql-data-directory-location) of mysql:

Comment: `rm -r '/path/to/drupal_db'` [man_pages](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rm1.html)