# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket homebrew

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I recently tried installing MySQL with homebrew (`brew install mysql`) and when I try to run it I get the following error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

There is no `/tmp/mysql.sock` nor a `/var/lib/mysql.sock`.

I've searched and haven't found any `mysql.sock` file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can see this link GeekHades answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847069/mysql-sock-is-not-created-osx/41605617#41605617

Comment: I brew installed mysql and had the same issue after my laptop battery died and forced an incomplete shutdown. It's worth running `mysqld` to check things and ensure MySQL shut down properly last time. If it had a 'dirty' shutdown (e.g. if a laptop battery forces a system shutdown) this should clean it up. Then you can start MySQL server again: `mysql.server start`.

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378429/2641861

Comment: This occurred for me after restoring a new Mac Mini from a Time Machine backup. I had to uninstall mysql@5.7 and reinstall it for it to start working. Bit a hammer but was relatively painless since all my configurations were retained.

Answer (score 117):

When you got the server running via

> `mysql.server start`

you should see the socket in */tmp/mysql.sock*. However, the system seems to expect it in */var/mysql/mysql.sock*. To fix this, you have to create a symlink in */var/mysql*:

> `sudo mkdir /var/mysql`
>
> `sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock`

This solved it for me. Now my phpMyAdmin works happily with *localhost* **and** *127.0.0.1*.

Credit goes to [**Henry**](http://www.getsymphony.com/discuss/thread/82299/)

Comment: When I try `mysql.server start` I get `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/lyahdav-C02R32HCG8WM.pid)`. I needed an older version of MySQL, installed via `brew install mysql@5.6`.

Comment: running. `mysql.server start` fixed it for me

Comment: @EB it's been a while since I had this issue but looking back at my comment, you tried the workaround to install an older version of MySQL? Other than that I'm out of ideas unfortunately.

Comment: The problem gets resolved when you re-install MySQL but then you have the so long backup-restore routine. Then, it also breaks again because my computer closes itself unexpectedly. I don't if this is an out of memory issue but everytime my computer closes, mysql gets broken with 2002

Comment: @LironYahdav What made you come to the conclusion you needed an older version of MySQL?

Comment: @crmpicco I unfortunately don't remember. Hopefully someone else could chime in.

Comment: I did all that and got: 
```
.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/Saranshs-MacBook-Pro-2.local.pid).
```

Comment: Do any of these answers apply to a homebrew-installed mysql?

Comment: @DavidRhoden Sure, that's what the original question was about.

Comment: @AAGD: I ask because in my current setup `mysql.server start` starts the pre-installed mysql instead of the homebrew-installed one. Or at least I think it does.

Comment: @DavidRhoden Maybe you missed a step during installation? This would be off-topic here, maybe go through https://flaviocopes.com/mysql-how-to-install/ or some other tut to find a fix...

Answer (score 105):

**Warning, this will wipe your databases, take a backup if you wish to keep them**

I had some directories left from another mysql(8.0) installation, that were not removed.

I solved this by doing the following:

First uninstall mysql

```
brew uninstall mysql@5.6
```

Delete the folders/files that were not removed

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
rm /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

Reinstall mysql and link it

```
brew install mysql@5.6
brew link --force mysql@5.6
```

Enable and start the service

```
brew services start mysql@5.6
```

Comment: Seems like the issue for me was that I still had /usr/local/var/mysql after a previous installation. Removing did the trick! Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I needed to run the "mysql_secure_installation" step mentioned by homebrew before this error disappeared.

Comment: This finally worked for me (after trying 5 other answers across various questions), though I knew beforehand that removing the mysql folder would obliterate my local databases, so I used `mv /usr/local/var/mysql /usr/local/var/mysql_prev` and `mv /usr/local/etc/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf_prev` instead just in case. I then can compare the differences using the `diff` command if I want to. I'm using macOS Big Sur.

Comment: Warning:  This will remove all of your databases, make a backup first and run mysql_secure_installation after all steps.

Comment: On Mac Os Monterey M1 my.cnf is in /opt/homebrew/etc

Answer (score 66):

Looks like your mysql server is not started. I usually run the stop command and then start it again:

```
mysqld stop
mysql.server start
```

Same error, and this works for me.

Comment: . ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/myHostName.pid).
?

Comment: I did a `mysqld &` per a comment above, but I think it probably would do the same thing as `mysqld stop`   I'm pretty sure in my case it was because of an improper shutdown.

Comment: I can confrim, in my case just 'mysqld' command was enough to restart the service, and socket file was recreated when service is started. From console output after service starts its obvious that file was created again: 'socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew.'

Answer (score 31):

Try to connect using "127.0.0.1" instead "localhost".

Comment: @Esteban MySQL will try to connect to the unix socket if you tell it to connect to "localhost". If you tell it to connect to 127.0.0.1 you are forcing it to connect to the network socket. So probably you have MySQL configured to only listen to the network socket and not to the file system socket. (Source: http://serverfault.com/a/295300/59101)

Comment: This helped me to force the mysql client to use the TCP socket, as I'm running an SSH tunnel on localhost to my remote MySQL DB.

Answer (score 24):

1. If you are able to see "mysql stopped" when you run below command;

   ```
   brew services list
   ```
2. and if you are able to start mysql with below command;

   ```
   mysql server start
   ```

this means; mysql is able to start manually, but it doesn't start automatically when the operating system is started. Adding mysql to services will fix this problem. To do so, you can run below command;

```
brew services start mysql
```

After that, you may restart your operating system and try connecting to mysql to see if it started automatically. I did the same and stop receiving below error;

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
> '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I hope this helps.

Comment: @berk it helped in my case to get reid of the error but prompt another error 
'ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Comment: Hi @PratikKhadka, the error you are getting now, means mysql is running, and you have authentication problem. According to the error message you posted, you are using username as 'user' and using no password. You should use a valid username and password.  I suggest you to check the following link; "https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,140320,140324"

Comment: No need to restart OS, just running "brew services start mysql" worked for me . Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AKS, you are right. Restart is not required to make it work. I edited the answer to explain why restart is required. It is required to see if mysql starts automatically when OS is started. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 9):

Since I spent quite some time trying to solve this and always came back to this page when looking for this error, I'll leave my solution here hoping that somebody saves the time I've lost. Although in my case I am using mariadb rather than MySql, you might still be able to adapt this solution to your needs.

### My problem

is the same, but my setup is a bit different (mariadb instead of mysql):

Installed mariadb with homebrew

```
$ brew install mariadb
```

Started the daemon

```
$ brew services start mariadb
```

Tried to connect and got the above mentioned error

```
$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

### My solution

find out which `my.cnf` files are used by `mysql` (as suggested in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/location-of-my-cnf-file-on-macos#comment58805600_10757261)):

```
$ mysql --verbose --help | grep my.cnf
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
                        order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
```

check where the Unix socket file is running (almost as described [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/troubleshooting-connection-issues/)):

```
$ netstat -ln | grep mariadb
.... /usr/local/mariadb/data/mariadb.sock
```

(you might want to `grep mysql` instead of mariadb)

Add the socket file you found to `~/.my.cnf` (create the file if necessary)(assuming `~/.my.cnf` was listed when running the `mysql --verbose ...`-command from above):

```
[client]
socket = /usr/local/mariadb/data/mariadb.sock
```

Restart your mariadb:

```
$ brew services restart mariadb
```

After this I could run mysql and got:

```
$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

So I run the command with superuser privileges instead and after entering my password I got:

```
$ sudo mysql -uroot
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

---

Notes:

1. I'm not quite sure about the groups where you have to add the socket, first I had it [client-server] but then I figured [client] should be enough. So I changed it and it still works.
2. When running `mariadb_config | grep socket` I get:
   `--socket [/tmp/mysql.sock]`
   which is a bit confusing since it seems that `/usr/local/mariadb/data/mariadb.sock` is the actual place (at least on my machine)
3. I wonder where I can configure the `/usr/local/mariadb/data/mariadb.sock` to actually be `/tmp/mysql.sock`so I can use the default settings instead of having to edit my `.my.cnf` (but I'm too tired now to figure that out...)
4. At some point I also did things mentioned in other answers before coming up with this.

Answer (score 7):

The file `/tmp/mysql.sock` is probably a Named-Pipe, since it's in a temporary folder. A named pipe is a Special-File that never gets permanently stored.

If we make two programs, and we want one program to send a message to another program, we could create a text file. We have one program write something in the text file and the other program read what our other program wrote. That's what a pipe is, except it doesn't write the file to our computer hard disk, IE doesn't permanently store the file (like we do when we create a file and save it.)

A Socket is the exact same as a Pipe. The difference is that Sockets are usually used over a network -- between computers. A Socket sends information to another computer, or receives information from another computer. Both Pipes and Sockets use a temporary file to share so that they can 'communicate'.

It's difficult to discern which one MySql is using in this case. Doesn't matter though.

The command `mysql.server start` should get the 'server' (program) running its infinite loop that will create that special-file and wait for changes (`listen` for writes).

After that, a common issue might be that the MySql program doesn't have permission to create a file on your machine, so you might have to give it root privileges

```
sudo mysql.server start
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks. I just ran `mysql.server start`, `mysql.server stop`, and then started up the service via homebrew again with `brew services start mysql@5.7` and things ran smoothly.

Answer (score 5):

After installing macos mojave, had to wipe mysql folder under `/usr/local/var/mysql` and then reinstall via `brew install mysql` otherwise permission related things would come up all over the place.

Comment: I solved my issue with your answer, I had installed previously mysql and then tryied to downgrade to mysql@5.6

Comment: Thanks dude. it solved my problem too. removing /usr/local/var/mysql and reinstalling was solution for me.

Comment: Beware: removing `/usr/local/var/mysql` you will also remove all your existing databases!

Answer (score 4):

When running ***mysql_secure_installation*** and entering the new password I got:

---

> Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
> '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

---

I noticed when trying the following from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016376/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-homebrew/50478351#50478351):

> ```
> netstat -ln | grep mysql
> ```

It didn't return anything, and I took that to mean that there wasn't a .sock file.

So, I added the following to my ***my.cnf*** file (either in ***/etc/my.cnf*** or in my case, ***/usr/local/etc/my.cnf***).

Under:

```
[mysqld]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Under:

```
[client]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

This was based on [this post](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/for-homebrew-mysql-installs-how-to-fix-mysql-sock-path/660).

Then stop/start mysql again and retried ***mysql_secure_installation*** which finally let me enter my new root password and continue with other setup preferences.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the culprit was found in the logfiles:

```
$ tail /usr/local/var/mysql/<hostname>.lan.err
2019-09-19  7:32:21 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: redo log file './ib_logfile0' exists. Creating system tablespace with existing redo log files is not recommended. Please delete all redo log files before creating new system tablespace.
2019-09-19  7:32:21 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
```

So I renamed `ib_logfile0` to get rid of the error (I had to do the same with `ib_logfile1` afterwards).

```
mv /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_logfile0 /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_logfile0_bak
mv /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_logfile1 /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_logfile1_bak
brew services restart mariadb
```

Answer (score 4):

If "mysqld" IS running, it's possible your data is corrupted. Try running this:

```
mysqld
```

Read through the wall of data, and check if mysqld is reporting that the database is corrupted. Corruption can present in many unintuitive ways:

- `mysql -uroot` returns "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)".
- `mysql.server start` returns "ERROR! The server quit without updating PID".
- Sequel Pro and MySQL Workbench responds that they can't connect to MySQL on localhost or 127.0.0.1.

To recover your data, open my.cnf and add the following line in the `[mysqld]` section:

```
innodb_force_recovery=1
```

Restart mysqld:

```
$ brew services restart mysql@5.6
```

Now you can connect to it, but it’s in limited read-only mode.

If you're using InnoDB, run this to export all your data:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases --add-drop-database --add-drop-table > data-recovery.sql
```

The file is created in your ~ dir. It may take some time.

Once finished, remove `innodb_force_recovery=1` from my.cnf, then restart mysql in normal mode:

```
$ brew services restart mysql@5.6
```

Drop all the databases. I did this using Sequel Pro. **This deletes all your original data.** Make sure your data-recovery.sql looks good before doing this. Also consider backing up `/usr/local/var/mysql` to be extra careful.

Then restore the databases, tables, and data with this:

```
$ mysql -uroot < ~/data-recovery.sql
```

This can be a long import/restoration process. Once complete, you’re good to go!

Thanks go to https://severalnines.com/database-blog/my-mysql-database-corrupted-what-do-i-do-now for the recovery instructions. The link has further instructions on MyISAM recovery.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error and this is what helped me:

```
$ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
$launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
$mysql -uroot
mysql>
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem on my mac and solved it, by following the following tutorials

https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/installing-mariadb-10116-mac-os-x-homebrew

But don't forget to kill or uninstall the old version before continuing.

Commands:

```
brew uninstall mariadb

xcode-select --install

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" - See more at: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/installing-mariadb-10116-mac-os-x-homebrew#sthash.XQoxRoJp.dpuf

brew doctor

brew update

brew info mariadb

brew install mariadb

mysql_install_db

mysql.server start
```

Comment: Please explain with some brief examples how the link you provided, helped you out. Links can disappear, and therefore this can be a reason that your answer might be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to these answers, In my case I had no local mySQL server, it was running inside a docker container. So the socket file does not exist and will not be accessible for the "mysql" client.

The sock file gets created by mysqld and mysql uses this to communicate with it.
However if your mySql server is not running local, it does not require the sock file.

By specifying a host name/ip the sock file is not required e.g.

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --user=xyz --password=xyz
```

Comment: my issue was I tried to use `localhost` or `http://localhost`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run `mysql_install_db` - easiest way is if you're in the install directory:

```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/<version>/ 
$ mysql_install_db
```

Alternatively, you can feed `mysql_install_db` a `basedir` parameter like the following:

```
$ mysql_install_db --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)"
```

Answer (score 2):

After a restart I could not connect with the local mariadb, a search also brought me to this page and I wanted to share my solution with you.

I noticed that the directory my.cnf.d in /usr/local/etc/ is missing.

This is a known bug with homebrew that is described and solved there. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/36801

fast way to fix: mkdir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d

Comment: This worked for me. Could not connect to local mariadb after `brew update` and restart. `brew services list` result was showing mariadb status `started` in yellow. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

just to complete this thread.
therefore MAMP (PRO) is used pretty often

the path here is

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
brew upgrade mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

If brew does not complete "postinstall"
I only have to use:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*
```

then completed postinstall by:

```
brew postinstall mysql@5.7
```

next step just start mysql@5.7 service.

It worked for me on MacOS Monterey.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this... it seemingly resulted from some leftover artifacts of multiple mysql installs on my dev machine. Every time I attempted to start or restart the mysql service it would crash. Ultimately, working through the err file helped me solve my issue.

Setup:

- M1 Macbook Pro running OS 12 (Monterey)
- Homebrew install of `mysql@5.7`

At various points during troubleshooting I tried uninstalling everything mysql in my Homebrew list, deleting `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql`, and reinstalling `mysql@5.7` to no avail. I also tried restarting my machine.

I was able to validate what was happening when the service failed to start by reviewing the `err` (e.g., `MyComputerName.local.err`) log that it was spitting out into `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/` when I tried to start/restart the service via Homebrew. In the beginning, I was seeing things like this that pointed to issues with the config:

```
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
TIMESTAMPZ 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
TIMESTAMPZ 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1'
TIMESTAMPZ 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I deleted `my.cnf` and `my.cnf.default` in `/opt/homebrew/etc` and attempted to start the service again. Then, the failure changed to this:

```
TIMESTAMPZ 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
TIMESTAMPZ 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Failed to initialize ACL/grant/time zones structures or failed to remove temporary table files.
TIMESTAMPZ 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

At this point I noticed several mysql lock files in `/opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/locks/` (`mysql.formula.lock`, `mysql.formula@5.7.lock`, `mysql.formula@8.0.lock`); I deleted those files, as well as anything mysql in `/opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked`.

After that, I was able to start mysql without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I manually started mysql in the system preferences pane by initialising the database and then starting it. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. After trying all these methods without success I did the following:

```
tail -f the-mysql-or-maria-db-error-file.err
```

in another console:

```
brew services restart mariadb
```

I saw the following error:

> "MAC HOMEBREW Crash recovery failed. Either correct the problem (if
>   it's, for example, out of memory error) and restart, or delete tc log
>   and start mysqld with"

So I changed the `tc.log` extesion to `tc.log.txt` and restart mariadb

```
brew services restart mariadb
```

and done!

Answer (score 0):

[**LINUX**]

Though answer is expected to be for MacOS only but in Linux we may face the same Error.

I was facing the same issue in Linux. I ran this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server start
```

and I was able to run the MySQL server

Ref. https://gist.github.com/vinodpandey/1a4b5b8228f9a000ca236820185fc3bc

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem, I did some tricks but for me it didn't work. If you used macOS, here is what I did. We start by uninstalling mysql and then reinstalling it.

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql
```

Note: you must have homebrew installed

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today 2023-02-23 after a homebrew update.

Homebrew had created a new my.cnf.default file, I backed up my old one and replaced it with this new default and restarted Mariadb and everything worked including the old root password.

Answer (score 0):

If you install mysql via brew in Apple Silicon( M1/M2/M3/M4...)
maybe you can try this steps

```
brew install mysql@8.0
brew postinstall mysql@8.0 
brew services start mysql@8.0
mysql -uroot -p

Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.35 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

---

if it still can't work

maybe check the log there

> /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/

like `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/{yourName}.local.err`

---

To delete and reinitialize the MySQL database (which will lead to the loss of all unbacked data), you can consider the following:

1. Stop the MySQL service (if it is running)

`brew services stop mysql@8.0`

2. Back up the current MySQL data directory (in case you need to roll back)

`cp -R /opt/homebrew/var/mysql /path/to/backup_mysql_data/`

3. Delete InnoDB-related system files

   `rm -f /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ibdata1`

   `rm -f /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ib_logfile0`

   `rm -f /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ib_logfile1`

   `find /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ -name "*.ibd" -exec rm -f {} \;`
4. After cleaning, re-initialize the MySQL data directory.

   `brew postinstall mysql@8.0`
5. Start the MySQL service

   `brew services start mysql@8.0`

Answer (score -1):

For me, I had installed `mariadb` long time ago, then installed `mysql@5.7`.

When I executed `mysql -uroot`, I get the error:
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Reading the answers:

- I uninstalled `mariadb`
- Deleted the folder `/usr/local/var/mysql`
- Ran the command `mysqld --initialize`

Then I was able to `mysql -uroot -p`