# MySQL (mysql_secure_installation) won't work after installing through homebrew: Can't connect through socket

Tags: mysql, sockets, homebrew

When just installing mysql on OSX through homebrew like so: `brew install mysql` and I try to run the command `mysql_secure_installation` as brew suggests, it just gives me the following error:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I tried ALL SOLUTIONS from this thread: [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016376/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-homebrew)

But alass nothing solved my problem. Any advice to debug?

When I try to check the existance of the socket file:
`ls -al /tmp/mysql.sock`
It says: **No such file or directory.**

Did Homebrew maybe forget to install something?

Comment: Did you start the mysql server?

Comment: Yes I did. `mysql.server start`

Comment: @ShivaShinde When I try to check the existance of the socket file:
`ls -al /tmp/mysql.sock`
It says: No such file or directory.

Comment: Could you check whether your /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf has socket defindd in the below manner? 
`[client]


socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: Tried looking for both files. Again, they do not exist. Maybe `brew install mysql` didn't work properly? Did it forget to install certain files you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often this is because of permissions, did you try?

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql

sudo mysql.server start
```

Comment: OMG! This worked! You saved me. I lost 2 hours lol.
I tried `mysql_secure_installation` again, and now it works.