# For homebrew mysql installs, how to fix mysql.sock path?

Tags: mysql, sockets, homebrew, perfect, mysql.sock

I am on macOS 10.12.3. Installed and running MySQL through Homebrew. Whenever i try to start MySQL with `brew services start mysql` or `sudo mysql.server start` command on terminal, it starts. Following is my `my.cnf` file residing into `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
user=mysql
basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17
datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
port=3306
server_id=1
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[client]
user=mysql
basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.17
datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
port=3306
server_id=1
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Then i try to connect to MySQL using [Perfect-MySQL](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-MySQL) following the instructions there. But failed to locate and connect to socket file. Got the following error,

```
[ERR] MySQL connection error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '' (2)
[ERR] Error msg: error("MySQL server has gone away")
```

Clearly it failed to identify socket file path which should be `/tmp/mysql.sock`.  But after running mysql server i found `mysql.sock.lock.lock` file into `/tmp/` folder, there were no `mysql.sock` file.
Then i changed the my.cnf file with `socket=/tmp/mysql.sock.lock.lock` . but same result.

I have no other mysql client/service installed and tried freshly reinstalling with homebrew several times. Same result everytime.

I have tried with a lot of other options but no luck. CLearly i am missing something.  Can someone please shade some light on it ?

How and from where i can set `mysql.sock` path ?

Comment: Partho did you ever find a fix for this? Running into the same issue following the latest MacOS High Sierra update.

Comment: If the socket isn't being created at all, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016376/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-homebrew/47435668