# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (62)

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I have started mysql using

```
brew services start mysql
```

and I made sure that mysql is started by checking it using

```
brew services list
```

it shows that the status of mysql is "started".

however when I try to run the command

```
mysql
```

it'll say:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (62)
```

I have searched online for multiple answers already but none of them would solve my problem.

How should I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/q/15016376/735926?

Comment: @bfontaine Yes I have tried that answer. Mycli works fine but I don't know why mysql just doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

in my mac, run this will solve my problems

```
$ sudo mysql.server start
```