# Homebrew - brew mysql 8 - Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I tried a lot to install MySQL8 via Homebrew on Mac 10.14.5. I was running MySQL 5.7 before that and did the following: I removed MySQL completely via this tutorial: https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks

After that I run `mysql` and got the message that the command was not known. So I installed mysql  with `brew install mysql`. After installation I did `brew link --force mysql` and got `Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19`

I edited `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` and added `default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` in the [mysqld] section. After that I restartet the service using `brew services restart mysql`

`brew services list` shows me this now:

```
mysql         started root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
mysql@5.7     stopped
```

However, when I type mysql in the terminal I get this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

The `/tmp/mysql.sock` does not exist.

When I change the host in the my.cnf file from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` this error will change  into this:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 54
```

Anyone has an idea what's going on here and how I can fix it? I also googled it and found various Threads, some are saying that the permissions must be changed to this `sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql` but this does not change anything in my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016376/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-homebrew)

Comment: I have the same problem.